# Interesting metrics from JMX

Tags: jmx

May I know what are the typical metrics that application developers usually find interesting with the use of JMX other than:

- CPU Utilization
- Memory consumption

Nicholas

Answer (score 2):

I would add:

- Class loaders behaviour
- Threads

Answer (score 1):

- memory usage diagram (you can see gc runs and detect memory leaks)
- stack trace of specified  thread
- jvm uptime, OS information
- all jmx exposed data with your application

Answer (score 0):

- Garbage Collector Activity (duration and frequency)
- Deadlock Detection
- Connector Traffic (in / out)
- Request processing time
- Number of sessions (in relation to max configured)
- Average Session duration
- Number of sessions rejected
- Is Webmodule running ?
- Uptime (if less than 5 minutes, then someone restarted the JVM)
- Connector threads relative to the max. available connector threads
- Datasource Pools: Usage (relative), Lease time
- JMS: Queue size, DLQ size

See also [Jmx4Perl's predefined Nagios Check](https://github.com/rhuss/jmx4perl/tree/master/config) for further metrics ....

Answer (score 0):

JMX can be used to support any of the MXbeans metrics.
Refer Java Documentation - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html
section Method Summary.